# AWS filtering out all instance profiles that have no roles attached

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I am writing a cleanup script that cleans up after Ansible's iam_role inability to clean instance profiles. In general, this instance profile has no roles attached, so I would like to filter all instance profiles that has empty roles object. However, jmespath has not_null function but not is_null function. So, my question is - how can filter out only instance profiles with no roles attached (boto3 or shell). Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @jellycsc - that's the problem. the command is `aws iam list-instance-profiles --query InstanceProfiles[]` and then tried to find a valid jq query to filter instances roles that have empty Roles array (i.e. no roles attached)

Answer (score 0):

Using boto3, you can try this. This is assuming the Roles value is an empty list, []. If it's something else, you just have to fix the code to what is returned.

```
client = boto3.client('iam')
r = client.list_instance_profiles()
for ip in r['InstanceProfiles']:
    if len(ip['Roles']) == 0:
        print(ip)
```